# Reasons for SOAP message getting cutoff and header duplicated?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, ibm-datapower

I have a web service that makes SOAP requests to our clients server (I do not have access to that server and have no idea how the web service methods are implemented).

The code on our part has not changed recently and has worked ok previously (and still works for most part), but the client has been reporting that a lot of our requests have been failing daily for at least a month due to "duplicate XML declaration" logged inside Data Power.

The SOAP message they receive is truncated (lots of data missing) and at the end of the XML, the initial SOAP headers are duplicated. It looks like they receive the message partially, then some error occurs, then try reprocessing it and that fails again. Basically it looks something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sendData>
       <requestHeader>
         //PARTIAL INFORMATION INCLUDED HERE
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sendProspect xmlns="http://webservices.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/policyacquisition/prospectquote-v1_0">
      <requestHeader>
```

What could cause the the SOAP message to get truncated? I am thinking about some sort of communication error between client and server, or maybe web server changes, but I was wondering if someone else has had this problems and could offer some suggestions.

EDIT: added the HTTP header received from the client:

```
POST <webservice> HTTP/1.1
http_racfid: <info>
SOAPAction: ""
MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
Host: <hostInfo>
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 41341
```

Comment: The are two HTTP modes  (also HTTP/2 which we will not discuss) 1) 1.0 : Stream Mode where are data is received in one stream 2) 1.1 : Chunk Mode where data is received in chunks and you have have to send a next chunk message.  The HTTP header can force to go into either 1.0 or 1.1 but normally uses the default mode in server (no header).  Best way of solving issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the request and response and compare the headers in 1st request with working app.

Comment: @jdweng I updated the response with the http headers that were sent to us by our client, it seems that they use HTTP mode 1.1. Could this be the issue? Is it something that we need to address on our side or by the client on their side? I am still learning about this and I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: Yes.  If you are no sending the NEXT CHUNK message you will only get one chunk and then a timeout will occur.  You could try following :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: @jdweng the request is created using a method exposed by the client, we just call it with some parameters. I believe that the request creation is done inside that method, I don't think that I can set the HTTP version. However, if this would be the issue, if the NEXT CHUNK message would not be sent, then I guess that the message would only be truncated right? But for some reason, the first part of the message is appended at the end, duplicating the SOAP headers.

Comment: Best to look at sniffer data.  The status in response when completed is 200 OK.  100 Continue occurs in chunk mode only.  Years ago I tried with with WebRequest to get next chunk working and could not find a solution.  But I believe it is built into some of the Net Libraries (not sure which).  HTTP uses TCP for transport layer (max size of ~1500 bytes).  A HTTP message consists of one or more TCP.  TCP will retry usually up to 3 times if no ACK is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`duplicate XML declaration` in DataPower typically happens when you have a stylesheet Action in your Processing Policy that doesn't detect valid XML and it tries to "fix" it.
This would indicate that you don't get the full XML from the server.

Enable the Probe for the service and have a look at the INPUT xml.

You can also in `default` domain start a Packet Capture as suggested in the comments or start a File Capture to get any messages coming in. *NB!* Both Packet Capture and File Capture are giving a severe performance hit so you shouldn't do it in a high volume production environment!

Another, less intrusive, way of getting the "real" INPUT is to add a GatewayScript Action directly after the Match action which writes the INPUT to a `temporary:///` file which you can review. This is "safer" as the `temporary:///` storage cleans it self up...